# SSIS : Deployment failed on Changing Protection Level stage with XML Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, ssis, ssis-2012

I am using SQL Server Data Tools 2012 version and **Project Deployment Model**.

I am getting below error while changing Protection level stage of the Deployment on Client's Testing Environment.

> The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

I have created Project parameters to provide Sharepoint Site Connection String and SQL Server Database Connection String.

( Overview of the SSIS Package : Extracting data from SharePointLists and then importing in SQL Tables.)

When I searched for this error, found many ways to set the package configurations for Package Deployment Model.

What is that thing which I am missing here in the configuration of Package, so that it is not able to encrypt decrypt the mentioned UserID and Password details ?

I have gone through many forums to get clear idea on this, but could not find any solution yet.

Is it something to do with the Integration Services Version and Deployment Utility version same on the Client environment as well ? Where exactly I should check the installed versions of them ?

The ProtectionLevel is set to : **DontSaveSensitive**

Please help.

Thank you,

Mittal.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Experts, please help

Answer (score 1):

The prob for me was the version of sql targeting. The sql target was 2016 while i was trying to deploy to sql server 2012. so just changed the targeting from VS project properties and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue where i was getting 'changing protection level failure.  Earlier I got package version issue when I run the package from catalog. Thats because i used latest sql server data tools in my development environment and version in dev environment was 8 but in server it requires 6. But even after deploying from server with sql 2012 version, the problem persists.  Later I changed the target versions in the project properties as suggested by patricgh and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

My case is slightly different but, in the similar lines.

Local SQL server version: SQL Server 2016

Server SQL server version: SQL Server 2012

If I open the ISPAC file on my local, the package gets converted to Version 8. But on the server, its version 6. So, if you try to deploy the version 8 package on SQL server 2012, you will get the following error.

> Deployment failed on Changing Protection Level stage with XML Error

To resolve this, Open the ISPAC file on the server and build it. Then deploy the package on the server. It should get deployed successfully. Hope this helps.